# Insert values into different server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, insert

I wanted to know if there is any way to insert values into table that on different server.
Let's say in a work environment that we connect to different server by mRemote.
I can transfer files from one pc to another.
I tried

```
insert 
into [Server Ip].[GlobalSales].dbo.sales 
values (3, 'F', 11, getdate () )
```

Comment: create a *Linked Server* in sqlserver management studio

Comment: You tried that aaaand?

Comment: Msg 7202, Level 11, State 2, Line 1
Could not find server '**Server Number**' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many approaches including

- Linked Servers
- Exporting CSVs
- Exporting XML
- Copying via SSIS
- Copying via DTS (older servers)
- Copying via BCP
- Detaching the database files and attaching them on the new server
- Using a high level language such as C#, PHP, or ColdFusion to copying rows one at a time
- Creating a bunch of scripts that perform inserts
- ...
- Typing it in by hand

When copying data consider:

- How much
- How often
- Security restrictions

Comment: what can i do if the servers are not connected ?
I can control on the db using third part software but not directly.

Comment: All of the above apply. You should research each of the options, and see which seems to work best. At this point your question is so broad as to be unanswerable